# Python 3 shelve hiding data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shelve, dbm

I scraped a large amount of data from a database and saved it as `"first_database.db"` using Python's `shelve` module (I'm using Python 3.4). I've had problems with `shelve` before (see [my old issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595029/python-shelve-having-items-that-arent-listed)), which IIRC were probably due to something relating to my ancient OS (OSX 10.9.4) and `gdbm/dbm.gnu`.

Now I have now a more intractable problem: I made a new file that's **~170 MB**, and now **I can only access a single key/value, no matter what.**

I know the superset of possible keys, and trying to access *any* of them gives me a `KeyError` (except for one). When I save the value of the single key that doesn't return a `KeyError` as a new shelve database, its size is only 16 KB, so I *know* the data is in the 170 MB file, but I can't access it.

**Am I just screwed?**

Furthermore, I have made a copy of the database and tried to add more keys to it (~95). *That* database will say that it has *three* keys, but when I try to access the value of the third one, I get the following error:

`File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/shelve.py", line 114, in __getitem__
    value = Unpickler(f).load()
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ''.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the issue, but maybe this alternative might help you:

https://github.com/dagnelies/pysos

It's like `shelve` but does not rely on an underlying implementation and saves its data in plain text. That way, you could even open the DB file to inspect its content if something unexpected occurs.

Note also that `shelve` relies on an underlying `dbm` implementation. That means that if you saved your shelve on a Linux, you might not be able to read it on Mac for instance, if its `dbm` implementation differs (there are several of).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just using JSON, which actually made things way easier for other reasons as well